# Can the infinite product of the powers of a transcendental number ever be transcendental?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, irrational-numbers, infinite-product

I plugged the following product into a calculator: $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{\frac{1}{n^2}}$$ and got a result of roughly 5.1806683. I would like to say that this result is transcendental,  as its only products are the positive rational powers of a transcendental number, but I'm a bit afraid of something like this happening: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(2n+1)} = 1/4$$ Or does stuff like that only happen with summation?

Comment: The infinite product  you wrote down equals $e^{\pi^2/6}$. It’s actually not known whether it is transcendental or not. It’s probably not even known whether it is rational or not.

Comment: But infinite products of transcendental numbers can be rational. For example, $\prod_{n = 1}^\infty 1/(e^n) = 0$.

Comment: The product $e^\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is to my knowledge not known to be transcendental or not, but by [Gelfond's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) we can say that $e^\pi$ is transcendental

Edit: deleted original comment cuz it looks ugly and i couldnt get hyperlinks working for the life of me

Comment: @RandomGuy The theory says that numbers a and b must be algebraic; neither e nor pi are algebraic

Comment: @Alexandra One way to apply Gelfond-Schneider to $e^\pi$ is that $(e^\pi)^i = e^{i\pi} = -1$.  Since $i$ is algebraic and irrational, and $e^\pi$ is not $0$ or $1$, it can't be algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all $\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{\frac{1}{n^{2}}} = e ^{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}} = e^{\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}}$. Now, $e^{\pi}$ is a transcendental number. This follows from the solution to [Hilbert’s 7th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventh_problem), proved by Gelfond and Schneider in the 1930’s. But unfortunately, $e^{\pi^{2}}$ are not known to be rational, algebraically irrational or transcendental.

And

$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} = \pi/4$, for proof of this result you can see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049802/proving-that-sum-n-0-infty-1n-frac12n1-pi-4-using-dirichlet) . It is a transcendental number as $\pi$ is transcendental.